# Inserting multiple values in a single cell of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to insert multiple values in a single cell of pandas data frame using the below code.

```
Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Declaring the list
lst = ['accuracy score: 0.550', 'accuracy score: 0.700', 'accuracy score: 0.730', 'accuracy score: 0.730']
fold = ['10']

#Convert the list to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst,fold)),columns =['Accuracy','Folds'])
df.head()
```

However, when I execute the above code, it returns the `df` as below :

```
    |       Accuracy        |  Folds |
    +-----------------------+--------+
    |accuracy score: 0.550  |  10    |
    +-----------------------+--------+
```

But I want to have the `df` that looks like below where in the accuracy values are stored under a single cell in pandas dataframe:

[image: Table]

So, how can I store the 4 values under a single row using pandas dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list` object for accuracy:

```
lst = [['accuracy score: 0.550', 'accuracy score: 0.700', 'accuracy score: 0.730', 'accuracy score: 0.730']]
fold = ['10']

#Convert the list to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst,fold)),columns =['Accuracy','Folds'])
df.head()
```

Result:

| Accuracy | Folds |
| --- | --- |
| ['accuracy score: 0.550', | 10 |
| 'accuracy score: 0.700', |  |
| 'accuracy score: 0.730', |  |
| 'accuracy score: 0.730'] |  |